# Unique bool check in DataGridView, updating the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a DataGridView with a bit column which shows as a checkbox.  The column is "IsDefault" by name, implying that if this cell is checked, all other cells in this column in the DataTable should be unchecked (only 1 cell in this column is allowed to be the default).

I managed to get this behaviour working by handling the change in CellContentClick event of the DataGridView, i.e.:

```
private void ViewIconsDataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1)
        return;

    DataTable table = ViewIconsDataGrid.DataSource as DataTable;
    DataGridViewCell cell = ViewIconsDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    Guid rowID = (Guid)ViewIconsDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value;

    if (cell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell = cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        bool value = (bool)checkBoxCell.EditedFormattedValue, previous = (bool)checkBoxCell.Value;

        if (value != previous)
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                Guid currentDefault;

                if(MyIcons.Defaults.TryGetValue(MyGroupID, out currentDefault))
                {
                    DataRow [] rows = table.Select("ID = '" + currentDefault.ToString() + "'");

                    if(rows.Length == 1)
                    {
                        rows[0]["IsDefault"] = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewIconsDataGrid.EndEdit(); table.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, clearly I'm trying to make changes to two records in the same DataTable here.  The first I'm hoping the DataGridView changes (when the user changes the state of the checkbox) and then I'm doing another change on the DataTable to uncheck whichever row already had the check, hoping that will propagate up to the DataGridView.  I need to commit both changes to the database of course.

Here's my database "update" code, which is kind-of generic, i.e. I pass in a select query for the whole table and a data table to update against:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(MyQuery, connection))
    {
        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter).GetInsertCommand();
        adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter).GetDeleteCommand();
        adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter).GetUpdateCommand();

        adapter.Update(MyTable);
    }
}
```

So, **the problem is** that I get an exception when I try to update the table after making these changes: "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.".  If there is no existing default, just a single record gets updated and all is fine.

Can anyone spot my mistake, or see an easier way for me to do this?

Edit 1:  In the above fragment, *MyQuery* looks like this:

```
@"SELECT * From Picture WHERE ID_Group = '{0}' AND Deleted = 0 ORDER BY Created DESC
```

{0} is the guid of the group of pictures I'm updating, i.e. a select query gives all records in the Pictures table which are members of that group.

Comment: Why the call to `table.AcceptChanges()`? Is this table the same table used in the update command?

Comment: Please show the actual update query. And did you mis-speak when you said you're updating the database with a `select query for the whole table`?

Comment: Well I have to pass in a query in order to instantiate the SqlDataAdapter, I think...  I'll update with the query I use.

Comment: Yes Steve.  If I don't call AcceptChanges, I never get a RowChanged event from the underlying DataTable, so I have no idea to start the thread that performs the update.

Comment: Also, it might be easier if the IsDefault column were unbound and you kept a separate table with a single row in it containing the id of the row in the primary table that is the default. You could then simply overwrite that id value in your ancillary table rather than having to remove the default flag from one row in you primary table and reapply it to another row.

Comment: Hmmm, that's one way of doing it Tim, yes.  But surely there's a use case for making multiple changes to a table and having them all update at the same time?  It must be quite a common thing in ADO.NET?

Comment: The select * from T is the select query.  I was asking for the statement that was used to create the UpdateCommand.

Comment: The update command is autogenerated by the command builder in the code above.  I'm not manually creating it.

Comment: BTW, the concurrency mechanism is very crude. The error is returned whenever RowsAffected = 0, which does not always indicate concurrency violation. If you execute `update T set foo='bar' where 1=0` you will get a concurrency error. All you can conclude with certainty from the error is that zero rows were affected by the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to [`AcceptChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx) changes the [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) of every row in the table to Unchanged.
The subsequent call to DataAdatper.Update(table) doesn't find anything to update/insert or delete.

You need to call the Update on user input (like a click on a Save button )

**EDIT** *To complete this answer with the findings below from @Robinson*

You could raise the `RowChanged` event for the table handling the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event and manually commit the edit on the DataGridView. Otherwise the RowChanged event is raised when the row lost focus.

Comment: As I said to the previous answer (seems to have been deleted), I don't know when the table is updated unless I call AcceptChanges.  The RowChanged event doesn't fire at all and I use this to know when to kick off the thread that performs the actual update.  Secondly, it seems to work when I'm just modifying a single row (when I don't have the code in that sets other rows to false).

Comment: Could you try to call the Update without the AcceptChanges? Just to rule out this AcceptChanges thing.

Comment: Also, I have tried the example on [RowChanged here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged.aspx). The event RowChanged is raised in response to AcceptChanges with its argument Action = Commit, but you get RowChanged events also when you add a new row (Action=Add) and when you change a row field (Action=Change)

Comment: See my comment about the spurious concurrency violation error above, in light of Steve's remarks here.  What's happening is that after the first update after the click you are saying to the dataAdapter that there are no more "dirty" rows, and so zero rows need updating, and therefore when you invoke the update command, rows affected = 0, and therefore the (spurious) concurrency error is being raised.

Comment: OK, I don't understand DataGridView.  I don't get the RowChanged event when I check the checkbox on/off by clicking it.  It seems to do nothing at all apart from toggle its checkbox.

Comment: Is the CheckBoxCell part of the underlying datatable? Or is it just an added unbound column?

Comment: There's a bit column in the underlying table.  I've not added it myself.

Comment: I am also not expert of the inner workings of DataGridView (Always used a custom control) but, in the [CellContentClick event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx) description on MSDN there are a bit of references on how to handle a CheckBoxCell.

Comment: I think I see what's going on here.  The RowChanged event only fires when the focus is moved from the current row in the DataGridView to another row.  It doesn't fire when the checkbox is checked.  This is remarkably stupid behaviour I have to say.

Comment: OK, you're right Steve, so I've +1'd you, but it's not the actual answer I was looking for.  Thanks to your link though, I found it.  I need to handle CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged and manually commit the edit on the DataGridView there, in order to get the update immediately, rather than when focus is lost.  If you add that to your answer, I can give you a tick :).

Answer (score 0):

There are **two problems** here:

First, DataGridView events don't send to cache the changes correctly, you must **use** an other event, like a **button click**, to force DataGridView to cache the changes.

The other problem "concurrency violation" its caused by inserting a new row in a table with an Identity column (usually the primary key). I suggest **use  another button for inserts** and force the new identity value in the DataGridView.

Whene you updates, i suggest to make deletes first, and next make the updates:

```
// First process deletes.
da.Update(dt.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.Deleted));

// Next process updates.
da.Update(dt.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent));
```